# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express doesn't start automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. It is set to automatic start in services. But when I start computer, it doesn't start automatically. I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP1 as well.

Comment: Is it throws any exception in event viewer? Can you start it manually?

Comment: Does this help? http://serverfault.com/questions/361669/sql-server-2008-r2-doesnt-start-automatically-on-windows-2008-r2-web

Answer (score 0):

I had a client that had this problem with Avast Antivirus. At this point their PC guy has not fixed it you. The problem with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express  started right after they installed it in April 2013. We can start it manually after start up.